# Android : FCM notification not fetching SQLite db records on click of notification when application is in foreground

Tags: android, sqlite, push-notification

Push notifications click event not getting records from SQLite db when app in foreground(closed from taskbar)consequently app navigating to login screen instead of going to Homepage. When app in background notif click event working fine.
How i can solve this issue.
My code is

```
var resultRecords = await objSisRepo.Get(); //fetching 0
```

FCM click action on the top of activity for opening activity

```
 [IntentFilter(new[] { "MyActivity" }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryHome, Intent.CategoryDefault })]
```

Notification click event start execution from `splash screen` instead of `click_action` activity.

Thank you.

Comment: what are you using for fcm notification?

Comment: For FCM notification i am using FCM google cloud messaging.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using `onMessageReceive()` method when notification is received.
Try to override one more method ie `handleIntent()`

Try Like this:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

}

@Override
public void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

}
```

`handleIntent()` calls in both cases foreground as well as in background when notification is received.override it and copy the contents of `onMessageReceived()` to `handleIntent()`.

Comment: thank you.
Still it is not working need to try something else. Once i fix it i will let you know.

Comment: did you put your copy the contents of onMessageReceived to onHandleIntent

Comment: I can't put exactly same content why because onMessageRecieve is having RemoteMessage param and onHandleIntent  havingIintent so i am not able to do that however i have tried doing:

 public override void HandleIntent(Intent p0)
        {
            //base.HandleIntent(p0);
            var ac = p0.Extras.GetString("click_action");
            SendNotification2(ac);
        }
Thank you.

Comment: This is how I have done it.  remoteMessage.getData().get("notification") .In handleIntent()  intent.getExtras().get("notification")